# How to interpret n & (n - 1)

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

How to interpret `n & (n - 1)`, where `&` is Bitwise AND?

For example `n & 1` can be interpreted as check if n is even

Comment: Check if `n` is a power of two?

Comment: It removes the lowest power of 2 that n has in its binary representation.